# CSS and JS are not working on live server while I transfer to there

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a coming soon page for my new portfolio domain, on a local server. When I'm trying to transfer it to my hosting panel on public html, just HTML file are showing but CSS and JS files are not getting included, and they are not working properly.
What do I need to change there for using on live server ?

I uploaded all folders, img, js, css and files.

Here is a link for live preview (Dropbox): [Coming_soon_template](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/159789737/coming_soon/index.html)

Here is my code for local server:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>This site is in under construction</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This site for now is in under  construction will be live after some days.For more you can knock me on there lover.mahabub@gmail.com">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com /css?family=Lato:400,300,100,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/TimeCircles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="coming-soon-total">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="header-text">
                        <span>A creation of Mahbub Rahman**</span>
                        <h1>Wait for difference!</h1>
                        <p>Long way to go just keep patience.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="example" data-date="2015-12-23 00:00:00">  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="social-area">
                    <p> Get in touch</p>
                    <ul class="social-list">
        <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com /m4hb4b">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/djjmahbub">Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Skype</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">whatsapp</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">gplus</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$('document').ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    $(".example").TimeCircles({
        start: true,
        time: {
            Days: {color: "#4A616E"},
            Hours: {color: "#5E524A"},
            Minutes: {color: "#2E2F2A"},
            Seconds: {color: "#9BA7B5"}
        },
        circle_bg_color: "#7F8382",
        bg_width: .8,

    }); 
});
</script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the path-structure (directories where the css and js reside) the same on your development server als on production?

Comment: Have you uploaded the CSS and JS files in the correct locations? Try using absolute file references in the header links to the locations of the files on the server.

Comment: Yeah i added all folders on same directories. First i uploaded them as zip from public folder then i extract them on there. that's it...

Comment: You have some problems with `js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js` - this file doesn't exist

Comment: Yeah But this file isn't using on that template exactly.